# Excel VBA: Paste formula in While loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed the following While loop and want not only add the data but also insert a formula into the mix. The formula is added but does not increment by row. See R4. I could write a separate While loop or For to loop but wanted to keep in the current loop

```
 While Not project.EOF
        i = i + 1
           For ii = 1 To project.Fields.count
           shtDetail.Cells(i, ii).Value = project.Fields(ii - 1).Value
           Cells(i, "T").Formula = _
            "=IFERROR(INDEX(data!B:B,MATCH(R4,data!A:A,0)),0)"
        Next
        project.MoveNext
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** your indenting is a bit off so my answer was not great: more like this:

```
While Not project.EOF
    i = i + 1
    For ii = 1 To project.Fields.count
        shtDetail.Cells(i, ii).Value = project.Fields(ii - 1).Value

    Next ii

    shtDetail.Cells(i, "T").Formula = _
            "=IFERROR(INDEX(data!B:B,MATCH(R" & i & ",data!A:A,0)),0)"

    project.MoveNext
Wend
```

I'm not following your comments about adding quotes - adding them to what?

Comment: OK thanks but am connecting to MySQLdatabase so the quotes do not work out even if i use single quotes it adds an incremental number but is in quotes